# How can I fix Cannot invoke 'getBytes' with an argument list of type '([Int8])'?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uuid

I am trying to compare two `CBUUID` and return the result as Boolean. The `getBytes()` method gives the following error in Swift 4:

> Cannot invoke 'getBytes' with an argument list of type '([Int8])'

```
func compare(_ UUID1: CBUUID, uuid2 UUID2: CBUUID) -> Bool {
    let b1 = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 128)
    let b2 = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 128)
    UUID1.data.getBytes(b1)
    UUID2.data.getBytes(b2)
    if memcmp(b1, b2, UUID1.data.count) == 0 {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I have the Objective-C working version of the method:

```
-(int) compareCBUUID:(CBUUID *) UUID1 UUID2:(CBUUID *)UUID2 {
    char b1[128];
    char b2[128];
    [UUID1.data getBytes:b1];
    [UUID2.data getBytes:b2];
    if (memcmp(b1, b2, UUID1.data.length) == 0)return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

I tried to fix it by adding length of `b1` and `b2` but It gives further error.

Comment: Why (in either language) are you getting the bytes? Just compare the `data` properties or the `uuidString` properties.

Comment: Better yet (in Swift), why not directly compare the two `CBUUID` variables? No need to access any of the properties to do that.

Comment: Note that the UUID has 128 *bits* = 16 bytes, not 128 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Data method `func copyBytes(to pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, count: Int)` and pass a UnsafeMutablePointer, allocate capacity 16 and defer deallocate:

```
func compare(_ UUID1: CBUUID, uuid2 UUID2: CBUUID) -> Bool {
    let b1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 16)
    let b2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 16)
    UUID1.data.copyBytes(to: b1, count: 16)
    UUID2.data.copyBytes(to: b2, count: 16)
    defer {
        b1.deallocate(capacity: 16)
        b2.deallocate(capacity: 16)
    }
    return memcmp(b1, b2, UUID1.data.count) == 0
}
```

---

Or simply

```
func compare(_ UUID1: CBUUID, uuid2 UUID2: CBUUID) -> Bool {
    return UUID1 == UUID2
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than simply exploiting the fact that `CBUUID` conforms to the `Equatable` protocol already?

Comment: Never said it is better. This is just a Swift 4 version of his code